# VBA - Object variable or with block variable not set. Variable as Integer

Tags: html, vba

I keep getting "Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" on the line `If document.getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")(tdNum).getElementById("no-piece").FirstChild.NodeValue = ItemNbr Then` in the following code:

```
Dim tdNum As Integer
Dim ItemNbr As String

    'More code here

tdNum = 0
    If document.getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")(tdNum).getElementById("no-piece").FirstChild.NodeValue = ItemNbr Then
        Cells(cell, 2).Value = document.getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")(tdNum).getElementById("col-action").getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
    Else
        tdNum = tdNum + 1
    End If
```

I've searched around, but can't seem to find a solution that makes sense with my code.

Comment: As a general way of solving these issues, set a breakpoint on that line.  Then use the Immediate window to investigate where in the chain of methods/properties the problem is (e.g. is `document` set to an object? is `getElementsByClassName(` returning anything?)

Comment: Can you have two arguments like this? `getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")(tdNum)`

Comment: You can. `("prod-summ")` is the ClassName, and `(tdNum)` is a variable as a number. So the first instance would be `getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")(0)` which targets the first instance of an element with class "prod-summ"

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem. Firstly, there was a typo. Rather than `getElementsByClassName("prod-summ")` it should have been `getElementsByClassName("prod-somm")`

And I guess the Object hierarchy doesn't like having `getElementById` after anything except for `document`, so by replacing my code with the following:

```
For tdNum = 0 To 10

    If document.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm-texte")(tdNum).FirstChild.FirstChild.NodeValue = ItemNbr Then
        Cells(cell, 2).Value = document.getElementsByClassName("prix")(tdNum).FirstChild.innerText
        Exit For
    Else
        Debug.Print document.getElementsByClassName("prod-somm-texte")(tdNum).FirstChild.FirstChild.NodeValue
    End If

Next tdNum
```

And that seemed to solve it.

Thank you all for your input though, it really was helpful!